# pip install throwing error relating to a function in setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, attributeerror, setup.py

I tried a `pip install /Users/me/git/sdk-python/` of my sdk-python package to a test project I have but it give this error:

```
(venv) Pauls-MBP-2:ibm-cos-sdk-python-config-test paulcarron$ python -m pip install /Users/paulcarron/git/ibm-cos-sdk-python-config/
Processing /Users/paulcarron/git/ibm-cos-sdk-python-config
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-req-build-cmc5fb_p/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        version=get_version(),
      File "/private/var/folders/k1/h29nn0z959q0dr6b44kxx_8h0000gn/T/pip-req-build-cmc5fb_p/setup.py", line 19, in get_version
        return VERSION_RE.search(init).group(1)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

This is my setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
# sdk python version check
_valid  =  sys.version_info[:2] == (2, 7) or sys.version_info >= (3,4)
if not _valid:
    sys.exit("Sorry, SDK only supports versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 of python.")


ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
VERSION_RE = re.compile(r'''__version__ = ['"]([a-z0-9.]+)['"]''')


def get_version():
    init = open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'python_sdk', '__init__.py')).read()
    return VERSION_RE.search(init).group(1)


setup(
    name='sdk-python',
    version=get_version(),
    description='SDK for Python',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author='me',
    url='https://github.company.com/org/sdk-python',
    scripts=[],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    license="Apache License 2.0",
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    ],
)
```

This previously worked but something has obviously changed. I'm just not sure what and based on the error, I don't know where to begin, other than it may be something to do with `get_version` in my `setup.py`. I'm also not sure where the egg reference is coming from.

Comment: It appears that `VERSION_RE` no longer matches the contents of `python_sdk/__init__.py`.  Did you change the `__version__ =` line in that file?

Comment: Ah, that's it. The version number had changed to include an underscore character. When I updated `a-z0-9.]` to `a-z0-9._]` it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had updated `__version__` to contain a `_` character but `get_version` contains `[a-z0-9.]` which prevent's the `_` character from being allowed so I changed it to `[a-z0-9._]` and I can now install the package.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install python library transformations and ran into the same problem.

It turned out that the python was stored or extracted in dos format (on my RPi) and that broke the regular expression search in setup.py that was extracting stuff like the README and LICENSE.

The solution was to download the library archive, extract it, convert the python file being scanned by setuptools to unix format, make a new archive, and run sudo pip install with the new archive.

Here were my steps for the particular library transformations:

```
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/57/02bfe4c63659c03980639cdb0e45a0a423910ebc1f441b53ea573de83650/transformations-2019.1.1.tar.gz
sudo pip install transformations-2019.1.1.tar.gz  
cd transformations-2019.1.1/
sudo apt install dos2unix 
dos2unix transformations/*
cd ..
tar cf trans.tar transformations-2019.1.1/
pip install trans.tar
```